# Where Do I Put the Scope for Related Models/Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`Transaction` belongs_to `Cart` and `Cart` has_many `Transactions`. I have a `Cart` view that has the following in it: `@cart.transactions.each do |t|`.

I want to limit the number of `Transactions` included in this loop to the first one. I also want to do this with a `scope :first, limit(1).order('created_at ASC')`.

My question is: Where does this scope go (ie. in the Transaction model or Cart model) and how is it properly implemented?

I tried putting it in the `Transactions` model and using this in the `Cart` controller and it didn't work: `@ftransaction = Cart.transaction.first` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first transaction, you can call it like so:

```
@ftransaction = @cart.transactions.first
```

Notice the plural transactions. The order for this by default is `id ASC` (unless you have a default scope defined), which should be for the sake of argument the same as `created_at ASC`.

If you do decided you want or need the order as well as the limit, the scope would be defined in `transaction.rb`.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error "undefined method `transactions'"

Comment: You have defined `has_many :transactions` in your cart model?

Comment: Yeah, I have that defined, for some reason, it works with @cart.transactions instead of Cart.transactions.

Comment: Doh, yeah, you're right. Have updated my example to remove the typo. Transaction is a reserved work in Rails, so watch out for any funny behaviour you might see.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I tried this and it worked:

`@ftransaction = @cart.transactions.first`